# FE Exam practice: "How many years until you're a millionaire?"

Tags: civil-engineering, mathematics, industrial-engineering

### One of the early questions in the NCEES FE Industrial/Systems Exam studyguide has a solution that I can't decipher.
The question is as follows:

- 

### `Bob wants to be a millionaire. To achieve this goal, at the end of the year he invests $5000 each year into an account that pays 10% interest, compounded yearly. How many years will it take Bob to reach this goal?`

- 

The part I need help with is the solution to this problem, it's in the image below within the red box. I have no idea how it gets from (5000)((1+0.1)^n - 1)/0.1) to 21 = 1.1^n. **Can anyone provide an alternate solution or some explanation?** Thank you!

[image]

Comment: This is a maths question, not engineering. Wrong site.

Comment: This is a straight out Engineering Economics question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not doing notation for this, it's simple algebra.

X = 1,000,000 = 5000 / .1 * ((1.1)^n - 1)

1,000,000 = 50,000(1.1)^n - 50,000

1,050,000 = 50,000(1.1^n)

divide both sides by 50,000

21 = 1.1^n

etc.